# Do page splits happen at NON -UNIQUE clustered index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I know that page splits happen at unique clustered index where there is no free space or to maintain the order of the uniqueness in a page.

Does a page split also happen at NON-UNIQUE clustered index since it doesn't need to maintain the uniqueness, but still it has a hidden value which contains page identifier?

Comment: If you create a **non-unique** clustered index, then SQL Server will automatically add a 4-byte **uniquefier** to your data, and make the index unique again. And so yes - it's behavior is exactly the same as a unique clustered index that you created as unique to start with

Answer (score 1):

Page splits have nothing much to do with uniqueness.

I have no idea what you mean by "the order of the uniqueness in a page".

SQL Server makes all non unique indexes unique behind the scenes anyway* but even if it didn't page splits would still have to occur if a row widens and no longer fits on the page or if a new row needs to be inserted on a full page to maintain index order.

*For a clustered index by adding a uniquifier to any second or subsequent duplicate values and for non clustered indexes by adding the logical or physical row identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Page splits may occur in all b-tree indexes (clustered, non-clustered, unique, non-unique) when key values are not inserted incrementally in key sequence or an index/data row is updated to exceed the 8K page size.

"Page identifier" is not the correct term. All rows have a unique row locator which is the clustered index key, plus an incremental 4-byte uniqueifier for duplicate key values. When no clustered index exists (heap), the row locator is the physical location (file/page/slot).

The internal uniqueifer added to non-unique clustered indexes is incremental so page splits will not occur when inserting new rows as long as the index key is greater than or equal to the last one in the table.